# Strange conversion of time- and datetime-format in knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datetime, knockout.js

I have a table in my SQL Server database with two column
 'whenDateTime' (datetime,null)
 'duration'  (time(7),null)

From my javascript I call a JSON-service with

```
 $.getJSON("myService/GetAllHappenings",
     function (allData) {
         var mappedAction = $.map(allData, function (item) {
              return new Happening(item)
         });
      self.Happenings(mappedAction);

      //... some other code...
 });
```

where

```
self.Happenings = ko.observableArray();
```

When inspecting "myService/GetAllHappenings" as an URL in my browser (Firefox) I get:

```
<duration>PT1M</duration>
<whenDateTime>2014-11-12T11:26:00</whenDateTime>
```

In the database the values are:

```
sduration           whenDateTime
00:01:00.0000000    2014-11-12 11:26:00.000
```

But when I step through the $.getJSON the values are ok until the line

```
self.Happenings(mappedAction);
```

Before this line mappedAction contains the data

```
"2014-11-12T11:26:00"
"00:01:00"
```

But just after this line the data are transformed into

```
"30.06.2020 11:26"
"00:00"
```

How can this happen? 
And how can I fix this?

Comment: yeah i faced such scenarios and effective fix should be dont use `datetime` type use `string` so datetime will be stable to & fro(controller<-->viewmodel)

Comment: Good advice! Thanx.
However found the reason: I was binding the variables to an input field and Trent Richardsons datetimepicker. I didm´t think the actual binding was finding place at the step through time, but I found it was the datetimepickers "fault". So now I´m implementing a parser for Date and Time.

Comment: Good luck .always be cautious while dealing with date/datetime. cheers

Comment: @supercool thnxx got the same error and resolved it

Answer (score 0):

I think [super cool's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424094/strange-conversion-of-time-and-datetime-format-in-knockout-js#comment43293543_27424094) is good.  I've ran into weird problems trying to instantiate jQuery-UI datepickers on top of `<input type="text">` elements that are supposed to display `datetimes` when I send them over as `datetimes`.